# Java Process can't read Factorio's output via standard IO redirection

Tags: java, executable

In Java, I am trying to create a console program to execute [Factorio](https://www.factorio.com/), (note that there is no code that I can control or view there.) a game written in C++ with specific parameters. (That are calculated based on my input.) I can succesfully run it, but I want it's output stream to be redirected to my console output. I tried several methods:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.directory(executable.getParentFile());
builder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
Process fact = builder.start();
int result = fact.waitFor();
```

Gives no output

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.directory(executable.getParentFile());
builder.inheritIO();
Process fact = builder.start();
int result = fact.waitFor();
```

Gives no output

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.directory(executable.getParentFile());
Process fact = builder.start();
try(InputStream inp = fact.getInputStream()){
    do{
        inp.transferTo(System.out);
    }while(factorio.isAlive());
    inp.transferTo(System.out);
}
System.out.println();
int result = fact.waitFor();
```

Prints an empty line.

When I run the same command in the cmd myself, Factorio gives it's console output just fine. It always prints some text with each line prefixed with the number of seconds since the start of the software.

How can I print out the subprocess's output to the console? What did I do wrong in these methods?

Comment: Are you using Windows? Then make sure, that factorio _really_ prints it's output to `stdout`. I don't know factorio and how they implemented it, but it's quite common in Windows to _not_ use the standard IO streams (for whatever reason).

Comment: I am in no control over the code of the software. Nor can I view it.

Comment: Don't use the steam version, get the non-steam version direct from the website. Linking your steam account will allow the non-steam download.

Comment: I did link my steam account. In fact, I asked the same [question](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=53956) on the forums. The same happens when I use the non-steam version. Prints to cmd, but not in my app. Is there any possibility that the software does this on purpose?

Comment: I very much doubt it's doing it on purpose, I run factorio under rlwrap to get input-preprocessing goodness, I pipe its output through awk to do production-timing benchmarks, both work great.  rlwrap uses pseudo-terminals, piping is just raw redirection.  Linking your steam account doesn't automatically switch you to the un-steam-ified version, you have to download and run it separately.

Comment: Factorio could be making some checks about whether or not there is a console and writes to the log files instead if there is none. But I do not want to rule it out. (Also, I did test it on the non-steam version. I got the same result.)

Answer (score 1):

This should be relatively easy. Try it with a simple process that you know works first:

```
Process curl = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "-sD", "-", "https://google.com")
    .redirectErrorStream(true)
    .start();

// Will block until the end of the input stream.
curl.getInputStream().transferTo(System.out);
```

Comment: I guess that starts to shift this question to software specific. Yes, it DOES work with applications that I wrote myself and with some other processes. But how can it be that a software writes output to the console if executed from cmd but not when ran from within another application? Can they test for it?